# Обрезка текста в CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Необходимо обрезать текст многоточием как на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Количество символов и предложений произвольное.

CSS свойство `text-overflow: ellipsis;` работает только в однострочном режиме.

```css
p{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden; 
  border: dashed 2px #99c;
  padding: 5px; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  width:275px;
  font-family:arial;
  color:#555;
}
```

```html
<p>Магнитное поле ничтожно гасит большой круг небесной сферы, 
  в таком случае эксцентриситеты и наклоны орбит возрастают.</p>
```

Comment: Каким образом будет задаваться количество слов, после которых надо обрезать?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko сколько влезет в блок, видимо

Comment: @andreymal ну там возможны варианты, не хотелось бы заниматься телепатией)) Хотя я тоже так предпологаю.

Comment: [Английский SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004) предлагает юзать некрасивые костыли

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko количество строк фиксированно — 5 например, а вот колличество символов или предложений произвольное

Comment: Если Вы верстальщик, то забейте, это нужно делать средствами сервера (обрезать текст при формировании данных на выгрузку)

Comment: @DaemonHK если бы всё так просто было))

Comment: @DaemonHK к сожалению, на сервере невозможно вычислить число строк, которое займёт текст, и обрезать ровно под пять строк не получится. Особенно если ширина блока не фиксированная

Comment: Вы же понимаете что это бред? Если описания будет на одну строку, что тогда? Какое поведение? Поэтому описание имеет фиксированную высоту в css либо кладется болт на эти 6 строк.

Comment: @DaemonHK не понимаю, что вы несёте. Если текст влезает в пять строк, многоточие не нужно. Если текст не влезает в пять строк, многоточие нужно. Влезает текст или нет, знает только браузер. Всё просто.

Comment: @andreymal ну раз знает только браузер, тогда ему и флаг в руки (то бишь js)

Comment: @DaemonHK ну вот, никакими средствами сервера делать это не надо :)

Comment: @andreymal просто обрезать можно было бы на 60 символов (допустим), чтобы в большинстве случаев было 6 строк, потому что вешать такую обработку на клиента кощунство

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможность сделать такое используя только css есть только у вебкитов и 12й оперы:

```css
p {
  width: 20em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: antiquewhite;
}

.webkit {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
}

.opera {
  line-height: 1.1;
  height: 3.4em; /* при 3.3 почему-то остаётся 2 строки вместо 3 */
  text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline; /* не работает с -webkit-box */
}

.both {
  line-height: 1.1;
  height: 3.4em;
  text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
}

@supports (text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline) {
  .both {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="webkit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
<p class="opera">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
<p class="both">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
(function($) {
    var truncate = function(el) {
        var text = el.text(),
            height = el.height(),
            clone = el.clone();

   clone.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            visibility: 'hidden',
            height: 'auto'
        });
        el.after(clone);

        var l = text.length - 1;
        for (; l >= 0 && clone.height() > height; --l) {
            clone.text(text.substring(0, l) + '...');
        }

        el.text(clone.text());
        clone.remove();
    };

    $.fn.truncateText = function() {
        return this.each(function () {
            truncate($(this));
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
$(function() {
    $('.box').truncateText();
});
```

```css
.box {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 110px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script><div class="box">
    <div class="box__in">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение. Только есть два минуса. 1 - `truncateText` меняет структуру `DOM`. 2 - если элемент на момент вызова `truncateText` скрыт `display:none`,  то работать не будет.